# Security report

Tags: permissions, security, auditing, third-party-software, reporting

I am looking for a tool able to perform a cumulative report of SharePoint rights, AD groups and IRM rights, at document level in a given library.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of tools available, but you have to try them and see if they fulfill there requirement.

[DeliverPoint SharePoint Permissions Management](http://lightningtools.com/products/sharepoint-permissions-management/)

[ControlPoint  from Metalogix](http://www.metalogix.com/Products/ControlPoint.aspx)

[Build the Perfect SharePoint Security Report](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/build-the-perfect-sharepoint-security-report)

You can try this free codeplex tool: [SharePoint Permission Analyzer](https://sppermissionanalyzer.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As a tool for cumulative reporting of SharePoint permissions, I can recommend [SPDocKit](https://www.spdockit.com). It drills down and view all permissions, explore permissions history, and create site and user specific reports, and it can also be used to manage permissions given directly to Active Directory users, Active Directory groups, SharePoint groups, users from custom identity providers, and create various reports to keep up with all these permissions.

*Disclaimer: I’m affiliated with [Acceleratio](https://acceleratio.net) Ltd., the company behind SPDocKit.*